# Backup Logs Before Installing Updates

Tags: 11.10, updates, log

So I ran into some issues booting my machine recently. Apparently after an update is when the chaos started.

I was told to backup log files but I am unsure how to back them up. Is there anyway to automate that process?

Comment: To back up your logs, sudo cp -R `/var/log /root/log`, what problem are you having exactly as it seem backing up your logs is unlikely to help.

Comment: Not sure. I'm very new to Ubunut and it was suggested it could've been an update that caused my system to not boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use periodic or scheduled backups I would recommend luckybackup. It is the front-end GUI to rsync. This allows you to choose WHAT and WHEN to backup. It can also run unattended.

```
sudo apt-get install luckybackup
```

If you do here is the download page http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/download.html

Log files are usually located in the /var/log/

You can also install a log viewer

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-log
```

This will allow you to view those files without having to use the terminal.